# Create empty box sized according to imaginary content

Tags: spacing, boxes

In LaTeX, is it possible to create an empty box that has exactly the dimensions of some content given?

Example:

```
\emptybox{abc}
```

would insert an empty box of the size as if "abc" was printed there.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use a phantom: `\phantom{abc}`

`\phantom` makes an invisible box whose height, depth and width are the same as those of the string used in the argument. There's also `\vphantom`, which makes an invisible box whose height and depth are the same as those of the string used in the argument, but the width is zero. Finally, `\hphantom` has the width of the string used in the argument, but its height and depth are zero.

Answer (score 8):

See also, the related commands:

```
\settowidth{\mylength}{stuff}
\settoheight{\mylength}{stuff} % height above baseline
\settodepth{\mylength}{stuff}  % depth below baseline
```

Example:

```
\newlength{\mywidth}
\settowidth{\mywidth}{plugh}

\hspace*{\mywidth}Hello
```