# What is the command for producing whitespace equal to the length of some string?

Tags: spacing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create empty box sized according to imaginary content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14595/create-empty-box-sized-according-to-imaginary-content)

I remember that there is some command for producing whitespace exactly equal to the length of the argument (a text string), but I can't remember what it is, and I can't find it in online references (probably because I'm searching for the wrong terms). Does anyone know the name of this command?

Comment: You are looking for a phantom: See [Create empty box sized according to imaginary content](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14595/create-empty-box-sized-according-to-imaginary-content)